# Power BI Temp Files?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

We have Power BI files created that with Direct Queries accessed mostly through https://app.powerbi.com portal. For only about 10 different PBIX files and less than 5 users, we are seeing our c:\Windows\Temp directory on a server add about 400 files/hour on one of our servers.

The files are created in pairs having same physical size as a PBIX report, such as:

- TmpDownload16226909155253318640583924312580.tmp
- PBI Report2014107552797016443.tmp

We have an enterprise gateway for a few of the reports, but it is setup on a different server entirely. Has anyone ever seen these temp files get generated so frequently and perhaps why? Would a personal gateway do this?